# WLan0 connection on pi3 similar device[yocto]

Tags: linux, yocto

I have a Yocto-Box that's that based on this [tutorial](https://raspinterest.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/configure-wlan0-and-bluetooth-in-yocto-raspberry-pi-3/). Everything is fine except Wifi. I can't get `wlan0` interface running. I don't why it is having problems !

here is what I've done:

```
root@MYONE:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:FE:48:3A:55:AB
          inet addr:192.168.178.88  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:FE:48:3A:55:AC
          inet addr:192.168.178.89  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76fe:48ff:fe3a:55ac%4804152/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4965 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:279140 (272.5 KiB)  TX bytes:3066125 (2.9 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1%4804152/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:12859 (12.5 KiB)  TX bytes:12859 (12.5 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:EA:FF:D2:06
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

this is the **wpa_supplicant.conf** file:

```
    ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="FRITZ!Box 7630 MO"
        psk="42483903143454867118"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

the data is similar to another pi3 which's connected via Wifi !

and when I take a look into the log file here is what I get:

```
    ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Line 1: unknown global field 'Passphrase must be 8..63 characters'.
Line 1: Invalid configuration line 'Passphrase must be 8..63 characters'.
Failed to read or parse configuration '/usr/customized/infrastructure/rootfs/config/wpa.conf'.
udhcpc (v1.24.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
No lease, forking to background
```

Does anybody has a idea how may solve this !

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @dagelf  answer, here's the output of `iwconfig`

```
    root@MYONE:~# iwconfig
    sit0      no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
              Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Encryption key:off
              Power Management:off

    eth1      no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.



root@MYONE:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   19037  2
wcn36xx                71132  0
venus                  66686  0
videobuf2_dma_sg       13896  1 venus
v4l2_mem2mem           16221  1 venus
tpm_spi_tis             4055  0
tpm                    50326  1 tpm_spi_tis
smsc75xx               38940  0
root@MYONE:~#
```

As you can see the interface is detected !

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is it on a similar device, or on an actual Pi3 or 3B or 3B+? Looks like just a typo in your wpa.conf file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that needs to be in the wpa_supplicant.conf file, is the details for a network to connect to. You can create a fresh file with:

```
wpa_passphrase Mywifinetwork > /usr/customized/infrastructure/rootfs/config/wpa.conf
*type in passphrase for Mywifinetwork and then enter*
```

The error message you're getting says that your passphrase isn't long enough. That might in fact be the only thing wrong...

Further on it mentions the above wpa.conf file - so I don't think it's using the wpa_supplicant.conf file you have. You can leave out everything from the > and it will just echo it to the console, then you can copy and paste it into that wpa.conf file. Also, I see you have the KEY_MGMT clause in there twice, and some spaces at the beginning - it might not like that - if it is actually using that file. I suspect a typo somewhere when you set this up.

You can test the wpa_supplicant.conf file - and connect manually with:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/usr/customized/infrastructure/rootfs/config/wpa.conf
```

That should connect you to the wireless network. Then, in another terminal window, you need to get an IP address from the network:

```
dhclient -d -i wlan0
```

Then you should be connected. But there are also programs, like NetworkManager, that try to do this automatically in the background and will interfere with this process, so it is best to use the system's preferred configuration methods.

The wireless interface will only show up when there is a wireless driver loaded. It is increasingly rare to find a device for which there is not wireless driver... but usually you can just use a USB wireless adapter for those devices.

The wireless device can also be called "eth0" or "eth1". An easy way to tell is to run the command:

```
iwconfig
```

It only shows wireless devices.

You can also try

```
iw dev
```

If neither of those commands are present, you can look at the boot log for clues, eg:

```
dmesg | grep -i wireless
```

Or

```
grep -i wireless /var/log/messages
```

Or

```
grep -i wireless /var/log/syslog
```

Or

```
lsmod
```

Where you can see if you can find the module loaded for your wireless device.

To see all the modules available on your system, you can look in /usr/src/linux*/drivers/net/wireless, eg.

```
find /usr/src/linux*/drivers/net/wireless
```

Or

```
 echo `for a in /usr/src/linux*; do (cd $a/drivers/net/wireless; for b in */*; do echo $b; done); done|egrep -v '(Makefile|Kconfig)'|cut -d\/  -f2|sort|uniq`
```

In very rare circumstances, you will need to manually enable your device by loading its driver, eg:

```
 modprobe -v ath10k
```

(The -v is just so it shows more detail, but you can just "dmesg" afterward too. If there is no "dmesg" command, you can also:)

```
cat /dev/kmsg
```

Sometimes wireless drivers or devices crash, in which case you might be able to fix them without a reboot with a:

```
rmmod iwlmvm
modprobe iwlmvm
```

(This is the driver for some intel devices which regularly crash on me.)

I hope you've learned about one of the important cornerstones of Linux with this!

Many bigger systems, like Ubuntu and Fedora, rename the interfaces to things like "wlp2s0" or "enp5s1n2" or "enx908723081" - in a repeatable manner - because depending on the kernel and boot process, if you have 2 similar cards, they could sometimes reverse order - such that eth0 is what used to be eth1, and vice versa - causing your device to connect the wrong interfaces to the wrong networks.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. But it's still tricky to me : what exactly the wpa_passphrase Mywifinetwork >  ... *  and should I now put it in wpa.config?

Comment: Sure, just type it on any computer - without the part starting with >. The output it gives you is the section with the passphrase to connect to the Wi-Fi network. Yes that part must go into the wpa.conf file. That file can be named anything, but somewhere something else is calling the program called "wpa_supplicant" and telling it to use that file. The > just Linux shell to write the output to a file, instead of printing it to the screen.

Comment: Also check that iwconfig shows a wireless device! If it doesn't you need to make sure that the Wi-Fi driver is compiling and included in the image and if it is not, report that to the yocto project.

Comment: last 3 were from me ;-)

Comment: no change :(  despite correct wpa.config file

Comment: Are you still getting these errors: 
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Line 1: unknown global field 'Passphrase must be 8..63 characters'.
Line 1: Invalid configuration line 'Passphrase must be 8..63 characters'.
Failed to read or parse configuration '/usr/customized/infrastructure/rootfs/config/wpa.conf'.

Comment: Answer updated on how to test with wpa_supplicant manually.

Comment: I guess you were write. after rebooting the wpa.config get writen by some process with this :/

Comment: I need  to see  why it get overriten after each reboot

Comment: thanks  a lot for you support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192741/discussion-between-dagelf-and-engine).